# Jquery: Each statement only affecting first item

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-selectors, each

I have a series of pages, the title of which is stored in a var.

I want to create a script that does something to the pages corresponding navigation link. On my site the title and the name of the navigation link are identical, so I just use an if and each statement as below:

```
$.each($("#menu ul li ul li ul"), function() {
  if($(this).find("a").html() == pagetitle){
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

The problem is, this only seems to loop through once. It only grabs the first li and a tag, and thus only works on one page.

Can anyone suggest a way of correcting this?

EDIT: html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">enu Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 3</a></li>
               <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 4</a></li>
               <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 5</a></li>
               <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 6</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 8</a></li>
      </ul>   
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @bipen added above - really nothing too special, just a nested menu list. What I want to try and do is trigger something if, say, the page title is "Menu Item 4" or "Menu Item 5" - anything within that third <ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your code is selecting the third `<ul>`, it will find the `<ul>` only once.. you have to select till `<li>` ....
i think u missed `<li>` there

```
 $.each($("#menu ul li ul li ul li"), function() {
   if($(this).find("a").html() == pagetitle){
//DO SOMETHING
 }
});
```

note: this works  just for the third `<ul>` i think that is what you are asking for..
  if all `<li>` then you can use

```
$.each('#menu li')... //as a selector
```

example for this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/4ETRu/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
$.each($("#menu a"), function() {
  if($(this).html() == pagetitle){
    //DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through like this in a much shorter way:

```
$.each($("#menu li"), function() {
  if($(this).find("a").text() == pagetitle){
     //DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

### note:

use `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this script

```
$("#menu").find("li").each(function(){
  if ($(this).find('a').html() == pagetitle) {
    // do
  }
});
```